Need help understanding a simple Git command
I made this simple shell script that lists out the last 5 commits without all the extra text:
+#!/bin/bash
+git log --format='%H' -n5

I'm a little unsure what the part --format='%H' does and I had hard time researching it.

In short, it outputs the long hash for the last 5 commits in the current branch (doc), so it's equivalent to git rev-list -5 HEAD

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log   all the options are documented

Did you even run git log --help? https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

You could also define an alias in git: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

I tried reading git log --help multiple times. For people that are not too versed with terminal commands etc, it's sometimes hard to make sense of all this stuff. I asked because I'm in tight scheduled place where I have to learn stuff very fast. I'm trying my best to research everything by my self, and I apologize for if I'm being trivial.

Here’s how you research what a git(1) command does:

Use man(1)

In this case the subcommand is git log so you want man git log
You can also use man git for an overview of the suite of tools[1]
If you don’t have access to man(1): Google man git log and you
should get this page


Search for the part you are wondering about

Use / in the pager that man(1) uses (assuming less(1))
In this case: search for --format



Specific to this command
Summary/tl;dr:

man git log
PRETTY FORMATS section
Go past all the built-in formats like reference
Go to “The placeholders are”


I have ended up on the man page quite a few times in order to look up
the various format placeholders.
The first place we find with the text search is:
--pretty[=<format>], --format=<format>
  Pretty-print the contents of the commit logs in a given format, where
  <format> can be one of oneline, short, medium, full, fuller,
  reference, email, raw, format:<string> and tformat:<string>.

  When <format> is none of the above, and has %placeholder in it, it
  acts as if --pretty=tformat:<format> were given.

So you can apparently give an argument like --format=fuller. But this
%H is a special case; when %placeholder is used it is a shorthand
for --pretty=tformat:<format>, in other words: --pretty=tformat:%H…
well I don’t see a reason to use that longform version so let’s ignore
that.
Let’s see the next paragraph.
See the "PRETTY FORMATS" section for some additional details for each
format. When =<format> part is omitted, it defaults to medium.

This is familiar since I always end up here.[2]
Here you need to go past all the built-in formats and to this part:
The placeholders are:

And further:
Placeholders that expand to information extracted from the commit:

Which lists %H as:
commit hash

Notes

git(1) is a “suite”. That means that it is composed of many
subcommands like log which you call like this: git log
A “section” in a man page is flushed all the way to the left so you
can search for it with the regular expression ^pretty formats (the
text is rendered all-caps but I’m able to search for it with
lowercase letters)



git log: This command shows the commit logs.

--format='%H': specifies the format in which the commit information is displayed.

'%H' is a placeholder that represents the full commit hash. By using this format, the command outputs only the commit hashes without any additional information.

-n5: This option limits the output to the last 5 commits.



The question is trivial and shows little research effort, but the answer is indeed correct. Why downvoting the answer rather than the question? I wonder.
